# log all occurrences of an exception type app-wide

Tags: java, logging, exception

I have an application, and in it there are about 100 different classes that throw type FooException. Sometimes these exceptions get caught and handled, sometimes they are uncaught and bubble up to get logged.

However, I want to be able to send all occurrences of FooException to a special log file regardless of how the exception eventually gets handled. What would be a way to implement this? Could I somehow do it with an event listener pattern?

Comment: Insert logging into the constructor of `FooException`

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov FooException is a Java exception, not one of ours. I could in theory write my own exception class and replace all instances of it with the new exception class, but that is not ideal for me

Comment: You can write your own version of `FooException` and create classloader that will replace standard implementation with your custom one.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all the exceptions of type `FooException`, special-log them and re-throw them.

```
try {
    // throws exception
} catch (AnotherException e) {
   //handle this one
} catch (FooException e) {
   specialLog(e);
   throw e;
} catch (YetAnotherException e) {
   // handle
}
```

You only do this for the occurrences you want to bubble up.

For the ones you already handle, just do the same thing but don't re-throw.